# I'm not able to call two $('#container').highcharts().getSVG(); in one single function

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get SVG of two charts on the page.
I've added a button, and onclick of this I'm adding 
var svg = $('#container1').highcharts().getSVG(); 
var svg1 = $('#container2').highcharts().getSVG();

I'm able to get the first svg but for second one I'm getting error 
'Cannot read property 'getSVG' of undefined'. I'm unable to understand how getSVG() has worked for the first time and is throwing error the second time

Comment: The problem is not with the getSVG() call. The problem is that the $('#container2').highcharts() call is returning undefined.

Comment: I recreated your example as live demo and seems to working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qeLtk58a/. Could you update my demo with your code to introduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! Your demo example works fine, but in my code it seems to not working